# Chrome 25.0.13 shows margin-top percents as percentage of the width and not the height

Tags: css, google-chrome

Chrome just updated itself and I now noticed that the new version isn't displaying my page properly. It appears that if I have a margin-top of a percentage, it bases the margin on the width of the page and not the height. Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-top: 50%">
            Hello!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a super short video demonstrating the issue: http://cl.ly/2T0c132T3U2y

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Chrome 25. A rule `margin: 10% 5%` causes margin to be 10% of WIDTH instead of HEIGHT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The W3 CSS spec here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

...says that this is as intended. So actually, Chrome *only just* implemented it correctly...

Comment: Wow. That's crazy, IMHO. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Interestingly, neither mobile chrome nor safari appear to match w3c in this regard.

Comment: is there any way to make the margin-top be based on height like it did before?